# Left Inverse over integer in agda

Tags: agda

I am trying to proof inverse property over integer (which is represented as setoid i.e `(a , b)` represents *a - b*.)

I have defined the negation part as `- (a , b) = (b , a)`:

```
-_  : ℤ -> ℤ
- (x , y)  = (y , x)

is0 : ℤ → Set
is0 (a , b) = a ≡ b

leftInverse : (x : ℤ) → - x + x ≡ zero
leftInverse (x , x₁) = {!!}
```

The goal of this is : `(x₁ ℕ.+ x) , (x ℕ.+ x₁) ≡ 0 , 0` 
I can not use `cong₂` here. I am thinking of using if else statement but I dont know that it will be proof. How should i proceed??

Comment: Could you share a minimum working example? It would help to test your code.

Comment: actually is0 is confusing. I just want to proof `lemma : (a : ℕ) → a , a ≡ 0 , 0`  which example do you want me to write here. I can give proof of left identity.

Comment: What is the definition of `_≡_`?

Comment: that is from this file : `open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as PropEq using (_≡_; refl; sym; trans; cong; cong₂)`

Comment: i.e that is a data type having one constructor refl. used from agda library.

Comment: No wonder you cannot prove this, the only pair that is equal to `0 , 0` is of course `0 , 0`. Did you perhaps mean to use `leftInverse : (x : ℤ) → is0 (- x + x)`?

Comment: thanks @Vitus Actually this definition works, what i wanted to prove.